# Possible to pass a value from HTML to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched SO but i didnt really understand the answers related to this question and they were all related to JSP so im not sure if it applies to my usage.

I have a list of comments on a page and when a user click on "reply" the javascript code is executed, but the javascript function which is running needs to know which comment it is going to be working on in order to insert the reply form in the correct div. I have information about which comment im working on in the html code but i need to be able to access this information also in the external JS file.

Is there a way to send this information from html to javascript ?

Comment: [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: how do you use external js file and for what?

Comment: Post up a relevant HTML snippet and some supporting JS with what you have tried, without this any answers will be purely speculative.

Comment: JavaScript event handlers are invoked in such a way as to make it possible for them to discover the element involved in the event (like a particular button being clicked).

Comment: @parchment Thanks but that doesnt quite work in my situation. If i would only need to send the article ID then it would work fine, but when having multiple comments on the page, each with its own reply button i need to know which reply button was clicked. Each div for each comment has "comment" + ID but from javascript i just dont know which comment that was being replied to..mhm maybe im misunderstanding though

Comment: Did you populate the comments container using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated]

You can use data attribute of Jquery

See an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9AJUJ/2/

html

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button class="mydiv" data-info="1" >button 1</button>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button class="mydiv" data-info="2" >button 2</button>
```

js

```
//when document is load
$(function(){
    $(".mydiv").click(function(){
        $("#div" + $(this).data('info')).append('hello');
    });
})
```

Comment: The data method would fetch multiple items and i would still not know which of these items were being clicked on so this seems to be working if you have a single value, but i need to know which of many comments a reply button was clicked on and while i could add a data-info i still would not know which div was clicked on, i would only get a list of all the divs.

Comment: Hmm, im not getting the usage of the this keyword in this context. I thought it refered to a JS object only. I cant see the connection of how it can related to the data-info attribute of the element being clicked on. I'll try to find some more documentation on the this keyword though

Comment: both viniciuswebdev and parchment had the correct answers which were what i was looking for. thanks for taking your time to help everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Does each reply button have an ID that matches the comment ID? That would allow you to know which button was pressed (this.id or this.name) and would correspond to the related comments field.

your input would be

```
<input type="text" id="comments1">
```

and your button would be

```
<button type="button" id="button1">Click Me!</button>
```

in your button js you can do something like

```
var buttonID = this.id;
var commentID = 'comments' + buttonID.substring(6);
var commentObj = document.getElementById(commentID);
```

Comment: Yes they have a {{ node.id }} field but this is only contained within the html code, so the question will be how do i get this value to the javascript function

Comment: I already have what your example suggest, the problem is not getting the value in html, i already have this value in that code. The problem is getting this "comments1" in to the external javascript function in the external javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Asume this is your HTML code :

```
<article>
    <header>
        Posted by XYZ
    </header>
    <p>
        This is a comment...
    </p>
    <footer>
        <button type="button">
            Reply
        </buttuon>
    </footer>
</article>
```

Here the JQuery code :

```
$(function() {
    $('article>footer>button[type="button"]').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().append(/**  HERE IS WHAT YOU APPEND  **/);
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to take into account that there might be 50 reply buttons, how would you know which one that was being clicked ? A single button is not a problem, but finding out which of a multiple of buttons were clicked is not that easy. I have a value in each div in the html for each node ID for each comment, but how to send this to  the javascript function is the problem. thanks though for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the markup of the reply buttons.

```
<button class="reply-button" data-commentid="42">Reply</button>
                        <!-- ^ Add this attribute -->
```

In your event listener:

```
var commentId = this.dataset.commentid;
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, im not sure however how the this keyword in this context can relate to the data-commentid field, i dont find any reference to any dataset function on MDN.

Comment: @user2959896 If your reply handling code is inside an event listener, like `...addEventListener('click', function(){ ... })` or `$('...').click(function(){...})`, `this` refers to the element that triggers the event. Also, here is [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) on MDN.

Comment: Hmm ok, i did find that earlier but since its not grouped in the javascript category like the other documentation i didnt know if it was a part of the language although i saw javascript in the code examples on the page. I'll read up on it, this seems to be exactly what i need in a clean way to do it, if it works :) ill try it out.

Comment: @user2959896 also, if you have lots of elements (50 like you said), you can get a performance increase by using jQuery's [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Instead of `$('.reply-button').click()` use `$('.comment-list').on('click', '.reply-button', function(){ ... })`

Answer (score -1):

What I have done (so I don't know if it is the right way to do this), is I have create my html code by a php class and give and and id to each div like "div number" + "answers".

So my page htmml looks like:

```
<div id="0answers"> 
    <h1 id="0title"> </h1>
    <p id="0p"> </p>
</div>

<div id="1answers"> 
    <h1 id="1title"> </h1>
    <p id="1p"> </p>
</div>

<div id="2answers"> 
    <h1 id="2title"> </h1>
    <p id="2p"> </p>
</div>
```

And so have all the information you need for exemple modify the title n° 5 when someone click on the div n°3.

Is that that need?

Comment: I have done the same you have already in html code, but the problem is that when a reply button inside of a div is clicked the div in questions id value needs to be sent to a javascript function. Seems like there might be a couple of answers on here now from others but i dont really get how they would work yet

Comment: I have answers in a real answers, for more lisibility

Answer (score -1):

So...

```
var i = 0;
var button = document.getElementById(i + 'button');

while(button){
    var p = document.getElementById(i + 'p');
    // and do what you want
    ++i;
    var button = document.getElementById(i + 'button');
}
```

Comment: This *seems* to be an answer, but I fail to see how this answers the question.